# how much memory is a stack object allocated upon creation?

Tags: java, memory, stack

I was wondering- when defining a new stack through the stack class

```
Stack stack=new Stack();
```

How much memory is allocated to it? It cannot depend on the amount of N objects (like arrays and lists, for example) because it is initialized without any data regarding the amount of objects that would be placed in.

However, it also doesn't make a lot of sense that it'd have a fixed amount of memory like an `int`or `double`  for example, because you constantly place objects in it.
Does `push` command increases the memory allocation of the stack?

I assume it is placed in the 'heap' memory?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this general guide](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml) for memory usage by object in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Stack extends Vector`, and [`Stack()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Stack.java#53) calls `Vector()` implicitly, which uses [a default initial capacity of 10](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Vector.java#153).

Answer (score 1):

I'm speaking from C#, so bear with me; Whenever you allocate memory for a local variable, it gets allocated on the stack, heap is for things like objects, which allocates a reference to the object and then the actual object, then the object reference gets used by the garbage collector to go through and figure out what objects need to be cleaned up and which ones don't.

In this case, I believe you are allocating the object on the heap, because all a "stack" object is, is a filo data structure.

Stacks in Java only store primitives that exist within a local scope, ergo the stack size in Java is usually pretty small, the size however depends on several factors and is variable at runtime, the initial size for example is typically calculated based on how much memory the compiler thinks it will need to run, then as it grows it will increase in size (I think Windows for example increases the stack by pages, which is 256 bytes of memory, but don't hold me to that.)

In your case, since you are asking about the initial size of an uninitialized stack object, the size is the size of the stack object, and it changes as you add elements to it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Stack inherits from Vector. The default constructor of Vector initializes an array with size 10.

Comment: Would you therefore define space complexity of a stack as O(1) or O(n)?

Comment: It's O(n), since the internal capacity has to grow as you add more elements.